# jQuery plugin, Tiny Scrollbar, with defer added to the javascript script tags, stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I got the jQuery plugin, Tiny Scrollbar, working but when I defer loading of the needed javascript files, the plugin stops working.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="jquery.tinyscrollbar.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
});
</script>
```

If I remove defer="defer" from the 2 lines, then the plugin works.
If I put the (document).ready script into a js file and defer that also, the plugin still does not work.

Does anyone know how to get this plugin to work with defer?
Or is there another jQuery scrollbar plugin that does work with defer?
Does anyone know if defer works with the jQuery Scrollbar plugin?

Comment: I found a solution for this. I used the standalone tiny scrollbar js library which does not use jQuery. It works when deferring the standalone js file. I'm GUESSING this isn't necessarily a Tiny Scrollbar problem, but more a potential problem with any javascript working with a deferred jQuery. In some cases, jQuery just can't be deferred.

Answer (score 0):

put $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); end of the tinyscrollbar library or make anther library and include it after  tinyscrollbar library width defer="defer"

Comment: I did try making another separate js library and include it after with defer, that did not work.